# onFocusChange doesn't capture most recent changes to textField in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, focus

**Background:** I'm making a basic taskApp and I have a addTaskFormView which has children textField widgets for the title and description of the task. Each of the textField widgets are in their own file and I pass a callback function from my addTaskFormView, which will set that state of some textEditingControllers in my addTaskFormView.

**Problem:** When the user navigates away from the textfields by clicking somewhere else on the screen I want to get the value of those textFields.

To do this I wrapped my textField in a Focus widget and have my callback function being called onFocusChange.

My parent, addTaskFormView, has a submit button when clicked calls FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(), which should trigger the onFocusChange.

However, what I'm finding is that I don't get the most recent changes to the textFields. I have to click the submit button twice to register the most recent changes.
For example, if I type the title "first" then click submit I get nothing. If I type in "second" and then click the button again I get "first".

**CODE**

*addTaskFormView.dart*

```
 class addTaskFormView extends StatefulWidget {

  var taskIdentifier;

  final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController descController = TextEditingController();


  addTaskFormView({Key? key, this.taskIdentifier});

  @override
  State<addTaskFormView> createState() => _addTaskFormViewState();
}

class _addTaskFormViewState extends State<addTaskFormView> {

  String taskTitle = '';
  String description ='';

  var viewModelAddTask;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    viewModelAddTask = Provider.of<addTaskFormViewModel>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    setTitle(String? value) {
      print("CALL BACK HAS BEEN CALLED");
      setState(() {
        this.taskTitle = value!;
        widget.titleController.text = value;
      });
    }

    setDescription(String? value) {
      setState(() {
        this.description = value!;
        widget.descController.text = value;
      });
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add a new task'),
        ),

        body: Column(
            children:[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                      buildTaskTitle(
                          callBackFunction: setTitle,
                          titleController: widget.titleController,
                      ),
                      buildTaskDesc(
                          callBackFunction: setDescription,
                          descController: widget.descController
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                        //submit data to hive
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        print("task title: $taskTitle");
                        print("task title: $description");

                      }, child:  const Text('Submit'))
                    ]
                ),

              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

*buildTaskDesc.dart*

```
class buildTaskDesc extends StatefulWidget {
  const buildTaskDesc({Key? key, required this.callBackFunction, required this.descController});

  final Function callBackFunction;
  final TextEditingController descController;

  @override
  State<buildTaskDesc> createState() => _buildTaskDescState();
}

class _buildTaskDescState extends State<buildTaskDesc> {

  String description = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      canRequestFocus: false,
      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
        hasFocus ? print('title has focus') : widget.callBackFunction(widget.descController.text);
      },

      child: TextField(

        key: const Key('task_description'),

        controller: widget.descController,

        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Description',
          hintText: 'Enter task description',
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),

          suffixIcon: widget.descController.text.isEmpty
              ? Container(width: 0)
              : IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () => widget.descController.clear(),

          ),
        ),

        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        maxLines: 15,
        minLines: 7,

        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      ),
    );



  }
}
```

**Extra:**

Didn't include buildTaskTitle since its essentially the same as buildTaskDesc. I can include it later if neccesary.

I tried wrapping my scaffold with a gesture detector and used the onTap method to unfocus, but I get the same issue.

I also tried another StackOverflow answer and wrapped a gesture detector inside my elevatedButton, and had the onTap method to call unfocus, but had the same results.